# How does web proxy work internally?

Tags: proxy

Suppose the proxy server is `A`,

and we're requesting `http://google.com/search` via `A`

How is this done actually?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, Wikipedia has a reasonable explanation of how this works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: Why "oddly enough"? Wikipedia has a reasonable explanation of just about anything. Also see the 2005 study in Nature, [Study: Wikipedia as accurate as Britannica](http://news.cnet.com/2100-1038_3-5997332.html)

Comment: I believe it was sarcasm, as in the OP should probs have just done a google search...