# How does a proxy server work?

Tags: python, web-applications, web, proxy, routes

Would like to know how proxy servers work (i.e. generally, how the mechanism works for the request process).

We're trying to understand how to set up a proxy server for our Web application.  We need several processes to access the Internet through a proxy server in the internal network.  Ideally, we could run custom Python code somewhere inside the proxy - especially before actually executing the request.

This is probably a really basic / dumb question, but now that I know that we should probably use a proxy, I am struggling to understand how they work and how we should incorporate them to our infrastructure.

Thanks very much!  Any information on this will be very appreciated!

Comment: Not belongs here, you'd better ask this question on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032885/how-does-web-proxy-work-internally

Comment: It's not really a server. you can't run python on a real proxy. proxy just forwards requests with optional filter requests on specified ports.

Comment: Why can't a proxy server run a little bit of python to modify the request that it is forwarding?